# Series in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm having trouble to find the radius of convergence of the following series.
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z_1^kz_2^k$$

where $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ are arbitrary. Furthermore, how can I determine the domain where this series is absolutely convergent?

For the first problem, I found $\limsup|z_1^kz_2^k|^{\frac{1}{k}} = \limsup|z_1||z_2| = |z_1||z_2|=|z_1z_2|$, so the radius of convergence is $|z_1z_2|^{-1}$, is this correct?

For the second problem, I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Maybe you want to read this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges if the radius of convergent $R = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \big|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\big| = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|z_1z_2|^{n+1}}{|z_1z_2|^n} = |z_1z_2| < 1 \iff |z_1z_2| < 1$

Comment: Careful, the ratio test xan sometimes be inconclusive. The root test is not.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: yeah.

Comment: What can be told about the second problem? This is the bigger problem in my opinion.

Comment: @diff_math: the same criteria listed for the 2nd problem. But to be sure, use root test instead.

Comment: @LAcarguy The second test gave me the same answer. This means that the domain of absolute convergence is the set $\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2: \ |z_1z_2|<1\}$ ?

Comment: @diff_math: true.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* This is just a geometric series with quotient $q=z_1 z_2$.

Comment: All results about real geometric series also apply to complex geometric series? I totally forgot this.

Comment: @diff_math At least the following result holds in both the real and complex case: The geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k$ converges iff $|q|<1$.